# Configure LEVEL for solr logging screen

Tags: logging, solr

Where can I configure the LEVEL for the solr logging screen?

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging
```

By default the LEVEL seems to be WARN.

Is there a special appender or a special file?

I know that I can configure the LEVEL for the loggers.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging/level
```

But there is no option for the logging screen.

Unfortunatly the solr documentation does'nt help here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging of the admin logging screen can be configured in the solr.xml (Not to be confused with solrconfig.xml), if you are using the new style solr.xml:

```
<solr>
  <logging>
    <str name="enabled">true</str>
    <watcher>
      <int name="size">50</int>
      <int name="threshold">INFO</int>
    </watcher>
  </logging>
...
</solr>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do was this:

To get the same logging setup in another container (Tomcat for example) as with the example Jetty server, you need to do the following :

1. Copy the jars from solr/example/lib/ext into your container's main lib directory. These jars will set up SLF4J and log4j.
   Exactly where this lib directory is highly variable. For a Debian or Ubuntu server using the Tomcat package available from the OS vendor, this is likely to be /usr/share/tomcat6/lib or /usr/share/tomcat7/lib.
2. Copy the logging config from solr/example/resources/log4j.properties into a location on the classpath. Usually you can use the same location as the jar files above. Edit the configuration file for your preferred log destination.
3. Optionally, if you did not place log4j.properties on the classpath, set java option -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.properties

Its here - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the logging itself works fine. It's just the web admin logging screen that bothers me. I can see all the log messages in the log files, but just some warnings in the web admin logging screen.